# Is there a way to update Angular bindings from/after dom manipulations?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Say I create an svg with ng-repeat and X/Y bindings, if I edit these variables through [SVG-Edit](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit) would it be possible to update the underlying bindings in a generic way?

So instead of the dom getting updated from angular bindings, how about DOM changes updating the underlying data.

Updating simple x/y/widths and heights isn't that hard to do manually in a non-generic way. But what if there can be arbitrary bindings set.

How do you discover all the bindings in Dom elements? How do you write values back? Would you want to subscribe to dom-changes?

Comment: You have both tags AngularJS and Angular. Which Version are you talking about? Below or above 2?

Comment: Answers for any/both are fine. I'm undecided which I want to use.